# How to convert the date into yyyy-mm-dd this format using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the date to yyyy-mm--dd this format.Here is my code .can anyone please tell me how to do?

```
var curr_date = new Date(date - i*86400000);
```

Output of the code is coming like this

> > Thu Jul 17 2014 10:37:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

but i need the output like year-mm-dd.

I am trying this also for year-mm-dd .this is working fine.

```
var date = new Date();
var date_format =(date.getFullYear()  + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getDate());
```

but i want to convert

```
var curr_date = new Date(date - i*86400000);
```

to yyyy-mm--dd
how to append var date_format and var curr_date

Comment: Here i am decrementing the current date to one day for 7 days.thats y i used "var curr_date = new Date(date - i*86400000);" I want these 7days date should be like this yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: "how to append var date_format and var curr_date" I have no idea what you are talking about, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use FormatDate
    $.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', new Date(date - i*86400000));

**[Reference Jquery UI:](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

Comment: requires jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: JqueryUI updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = new Date(date - i*86400000);
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var date_format = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
```